# Swift ui macos ProgressView Use of unresolved identifier 'ProgressView'

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, loader

[image]

I am trying to add a ProgressView in a macos project, but it is giving me the following error, looking on the internet I can't find any solution.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What SDK & deployment target do you use? It is available only in SwiftUI 2.0 / macOS 11.

Comment: xCode: Version 11.6, MacOs: 10.15.4

Answer (score 0):

This ProgressView is only available for MacOs 11, as you can see in this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/progressview

You can use the `NSProgressIndicator` and wrap it into a `NSViewRepresentable` like this:

```
import Swift
import SwiftUI

public struct ActivityIndicator {
    public enum Style {
        case medium
        case large
    }
    
    private var isAnimated: Bool = true
    private var style: Style? = Style.medium
    
    public init() {
        
    }
}

#if os(macOS)

import Cocoa
import AppKit

extension ActivityIndicator: NSViewRepresentable {
    public typealias Context = NSViewRepresentableContext<Self>
    public typealias NSViewType = NSProgressIndicator
    
    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSViewType {
        let nsView = NSProgressIndicator()
        nsView.isIndeterminate = true
        nsView.style = .spinning
        nsView.sizeToFit()
        nsView.layer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 0.6, 0.0);
        nsView.controlSize = .small
        return nsView
    }
    
    public func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: Context) {
        isAnimated ? nsView.startAnimation(self) : nsView.stopAnimation(self)
    }
}

#endif
```